# How to wait for a Vue function to finish with async/await?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue function that is called in a while loop. The function loops as desired and overall, it produces the desired results. The issue is that there are some areas of that function that require setTimeout and those don't have time to finish while these loops occur and for the related parts of code, it does not produce the desired results. The "vm.getResults()" function is an async function too, if that matters.

Is there a way I can use async/await or a promise to make it so the while loop waits for the "vm.getResults()" function to finish until it goes through the next iteration?

```
               while (i < data.length) {
                    (async function () {
                        async function getRes() {
                            let getPromise = new Promise(function (Resolve, Reject) {
                                vm.getResults()
                                // Can I put something here so it waits until the getResults function is finished?
                                Resolve()
                            });
                            var result = await getPromise
                            return result
                        }
                        getRes()
                    })(i++)
```

Comment: As it stands, your entire while loop could be shortened to `while (i < data.length) { vm.getResults(); i++; }`. You use neither `i`, nor `data` nor the return value of `vm.getResults()`. I assume this is not the intended behaviour?

Comment: Yes, the "i" in the async function is not necessary. It is a typo, I will correct it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple levels of `async` functions in your code, and each would have to be `await`ed if you want to wait until each iteration is complete. However, you really only need one `async` wrapper for the loop that `await`s `vm.getResults()`:

```js
const data = { length: 3 }
const vm = { getResults: async () => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(new Date()), 1000)) }

const loop = async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const date = await vm.getResults()
    console.log(`result[${i}]`, date)
  }
}

loop()
```